Getting Size Error When Putting Dictionary Values In One Way ANOVA Method
When I try to put the values of my dictionary into the SciPy f_oneway function it gives me an error saying that input is too short (must be greater than 1), but the length of it is 3 so it should be fine. I know I can just input the values individually separated by commas using the key, but I want this to work for unknown keys/dictionary lengths. Is there something specific I have to do or am I going about this completely wrong?
x = {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5,6], 'c' : [7,8,9]}
for a in x.values():
    print(a)
len(x.values())
______________________
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
3
______________________
stats.f_oneway(x.values())
_______________________
TypeError: at least two inputs are required; got 1.


I think you need to unpack the values: stats.f_oneway(*x.values())

Yea Vardan is right,
When you just give dict.values() it will return a dict object.
So when you use star it will return all the valuesin it.instead of the whole object.
from scipy import stats
x = {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [4,5,6], 'c' : [7,8,9]}
print(*x.values())
print(stats.f_oneway(*x.values()))

with out *

dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

with *
[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]
F_onewayResult(statistic=27.0, pvalue=0.0010000000000000002)

